# Construction of "special" cut-off functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $L>0$. Is it possible to find  $0<\varepsilon <L$ and a cut off function $\psi: [0,L]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

i) $\psi \in C^3([0,L])$,

ii) $\psi(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,\varepsilon]$,

iii) $\psi(x)=1$ for all $x \in [L-\varepsilon, L]$,

and $$|\psi'(x)||\psi(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2L}, \quad \forall x  \in [0,L]?$$

Comment: With (i), (ii), and (iii) you can construct a function that is actually $C^\infty$ using functions of the form $\exp(-1/x^2)$. Without looking in depth, I suspect you might run into issues with the mean value theorem on your desired inequality. How important is the factor of $1/2$ on the right side, and have you tried constructing an actual cutoff function of the type I mentioned and seeing if it satisfies the inequality?

Comment: What about splining a piecewise-linear function? Do you anticipate being unable to do this smoothly?

Comment: I don't think it's going to be just a case of connecting $(\epsilon,0)$ to $(L-\epsilon,1)$ and "smoothing out" the corners, because  $\frac{f(L-\epsilon )-f\left ( \epsilon  \right )}{L-2\epsilon }=\frac{1}{L-2\epsilon }$, so if we evaluate $\psi $ at $L/2$ we get $\psi \left ( \frac{L}{2} \right )\psi '\left ( \frac{L}{2} \right )=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{L-2\epsilon }>\frac{1}{2L}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1=\int_\varepsilon^{L-\varepsilon}(\psi^2(x))'dx\le (L-2\varepsilon)2\max |\psi(x)|\,|\psi'(x)|\le (L-2\varepsilon)/L<1.
$$
Impossible.